# Tag irregulariy: pronoun instead of pronouns

Tags: discussion, tags

Writing a tag wiki for [person](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/person) I noticed an irregularity in the tags used for parts of speech: They are all pluralised (e.g., [verbs](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verbs), [nouns](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nouns)) except for [pronoun](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronoun).

Can this irregularity be removed by pluralising the tag for pronouns, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't directly change the spelling here. See [How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or "zombie") tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags) and [Created a tag with a typo, but can't change it (or suggest synonym)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185184/created-a-tag-with-a-typo-but-cant-change-it-or-suggest-synonym).

The easiest way out is to change the tag under a few questions, and then synonymize [pronoun](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronoun) and [pronouns](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronouns).

---

Steps for future reference:

- manually tag a question with the new tag.
- merge tags: old tag → new tag

Comment: Tried that, but it does not work for me. Error message is:




Tags
terminology
gender
pronouns
The tag [pronouns] is too similar to [pronoun]. If you think this new tag should be allowed, discuss it on meta.
Your tags couldn't be submitted. Please see the error above.

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica I forced some things and replaced [tag:pronoun] with [tag:pronouns]. It should be fine now. If the right questions doesn't show up immediately, hit F5 a couple of times.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @prash!